# Chrome on Android not connecting to peer over WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I'm building a WebRTC app with a central electron app that browsers connect to. The scenario I'm testing is running the electron app on my computer (Ubuntu 16.04) and connecting from chrome (69) on Android (7.0). Following the debugging the offer, answer and candidate are passed, but fails on the last stop of generating the connection. The ice connection state switchs to "checking" then "failed". I'm able to load the browser app on my laptop and connect to an electron app on the same computer.

Should I be using a collection of ice servers? What do I need to make the WebRTC connection more robust? Should I not write my own signaling process and use something pre-made? Is their anyway to debug the reason why the connection failed? For debugging I've tried the webrtc debugging tab on chrome but all it says is connection failled at the bottom of the stack.

The configuration for my RTCPeerConnection is:

`const configuration = { 
            "iceServers": [{ "urls": "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" }]
        };`

This is the code I use to form iniate the connection to the electron app from the browser app (The function are attached to a ts class which are called in order: setupPeerConnection, setupDataChannel, makeOffer):

```
setupPeerConnection(gameID:string) {
    this.gameID = gameID;

    let configuration:RTCConfiguration = { 
        "iceServers": [{ "urls": "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" }]
    };
    this.connection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    const that:PeerConnection = this;
    //Definition of the data channel
    this.connection.ondatachannel = function(ev:RTCDataChannelEvent) {

    };

    //When we get our own ICE Candidate, we provide it to the other Peer.
    this.connection.onicecandidate = function(event:RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) {
        if (event.candidate && that.connectedToGame) {
            that.serverConnection.send({
                type: "candidate",
                candidate: event.candidate
            });
        }
    };
    this.connection.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(e:Event) {
        let iceState:RTCIceConnectionState = this.iceConnectionState;
        console.log("Changing connection state:", iceState)
        if (iceState == "connected") {
            console.log("Connection established with server");
        } else if (iceState =="disconnected" || iceState == "closed") {
            // We lost the user
            that.connectedToGame = false;
            that.onLeave();
        }
    };
}
setupDataChannel(onopen:(error:ErrorEvent)=>void, onmessage:(message:MessageEvent)=>void) {
    let dataChannelOptions:RTCDataChannelInit = <RTCDataChannelInit>{ 
        reliable: true
    };
    this.dataChannel = this.connection.createDataChannel(this.gameID + "-dataChannel", dataChannelOptions);

    this.dataChannel.onerror = function (error:ErrorEvent) { 
        console.log("Error on data channel:", error); 
    };
    this.dataChannel.onmessage = onmessage.bind(this);
    this.dataChannel.onopen = onopen;
    this.dataChannel.onclose = function() {
        console.log("Channel closed.");
    };
}
makeOffer() {
    let that:PeerConnection = this;
    this.connection.createOffer().then(function (offer:RTCSessionDescriptionInit) {
        that.serverConnection.send({
            gameID: that.gameID,
            type: "offer",
            offer: offer
        });
        that.connection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error contacting remote peer: ", error);
    });
}
```